# how to enable or disable a particular sampler or listener with command line options in jmeter

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am running Jmeter from jenkins pipeline . My Jmx file has 'Simple data Writer' as listener which I want to enable or disable based on the parameters from jenkins . It is possible to enable / disable the listener with right click but i could not find any means to do the same thing programmatically

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should use this command:

```
jmeter -Jsampler.YOURSAMPLER.enabled=true -Jlistener.YOURLISTENER.enabled=false -n -t YOURFILENAME.jmx -l YOURRESULTFILE.jtl
```

By using this command, you can enable or disable specific sampler or listener in **JMeter**.

Comment: thanks for your comment but  this `-Jlistener.YOURLISTENER.enabled=false` did not work . Do we have any property parameters of listener / Sampler type which we can use it ?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter [.jmx test scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) are basically [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) files so you can change the parameter using [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) editor before running the test:

```
sed -i '/<ResultCollector guiclass="SimpleDataWriter" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Simple Data Writer" enabled="true">/ s/enabled="true"/enabled="false"/' /path/to/your/test.jmx
```

Alternatively you can consider using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool, it has ability to [run existing JMeter tests](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File) and [change any parameter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) you can think of on the fly. Check out [The Complete Taurus Course](https://www.blazemeter.com/university/complete-taurus-course) if you're interested in Taurus framework